# Cannot convert Numpy array as tensor for input

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm

When I want to make text generation depending on various factors with an lstm model, when I try to use the data I want to use, I get a Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list) error while taking inputs. Below is my given data:

| state | district | month | rainfall | max_temp | min_temp | max_rh | min_rh | wind_speed | advice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [1] | [1] | 2 | 0.0 | 34.6 | 19.4 | 88.2 | 29.6 | 12.0 | [[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 1, 11, 12, 13, 3, 4, 5],[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 14, 15, 2, 16, 17, 6, 7, 2, 18, 19, 20, 8, 4],[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 21, 9, 22, 5, 23, 24, 2, 25, 26, 6, 27]] |
| [2] | [2,3] | 2 | 0 | 35.2 | 16.6 | 29.4 | 11.2 | 3.6 | [[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 54, 55, 21, 56, 57, 3,22, 19, 58, 6, 59, 4, 60, 1, 61, 62, 23, 63, 23, 64], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 65, 7, 66, 2, 67, 68, 3, 69, 70], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 12, 5, 13, 14, 9, 10, 5, 15, 16, 17, 2, 8], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 71, 1, 72, 73, 74, 7, 75, 76, 77, 3, 20, 78, 18, 79, 1, 21, 80, 81, 3, 82, 83, 84, 6, 85]] |

The code I am using to take input labels and data is as a follows.

```
labels=data.pop('advices')
ds= tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(data), labels))
```

The error I am getting is as below.

```
TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for 0       [1]
1       [1]
2       [1]
3    [2, 3]
4    [2, 3]
Name: district, dtype: object with type Series

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     96       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
     97   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 98   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
     99 
    100 

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

I am new to this field, someone please help me.

Comment: Based on the error, I guess the issue is that the elements in your array are not scalars but sequences themselves

Comment: Yes, that's it. And I know I will get same error in advices coloumn too later. I don't know how to work it around.

Comment: @Santosh Kumar: Did you already find a solution to your problem, and if so, would you be so kind and share it with us?

Answer (score 0):

Sample code which converts numpy array to Tensor.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
a = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
arg = tf.convert_to_tensor(a, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Output

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], dtype=float32)>
```